# TypeError: core is not a function with FusionChart

Tags: angular, typeerror, fusioncharts

I have an error that I can't seem to resolve, I use angular-fusionchart v3.2.3 and fusionchart 3.2.0 with angular 13.3.11
I have this error in my browser console :

```
main.ts:11  ERROR TypeError: core is not a function
at FusionChartsService.resolveFusionCharts (fusioncharts.service.js:44:1)
at new FusionChartsService (fusioncharts.service.js:28:1)
at NodeInjectorFactory.FusionChartsService_Factory \[as factory\] (fusioncharts.service.js:71:70)
at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3574:1)
at searchTokensOnInjector (core.mjs:3511:1)
at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3455:1)
at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:14518:1)
at NodeInjectorFactory.FusionChartsComponent_Factory \[as factory\] (fusioncharts.component.js:569:183)
at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3574:1)
at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:10417:1)

main.ts:12  TypeError: core is not a function
at FusionChartsService.resolveFusionCharts (fusioncharts.service.js:44:1)
at new FusionChartsService (fusioncharts.service.js:28:1)
at NodeInjectorFactory.FusionChartsService_Factory \[as factory\] (fusioncharts.service.js:71:70)
at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3574:1)
at searchTokensOnInjector (core.mjs:3511:1)
at getOrCreateInjectable (core.mjs:3455:1)
at Module.ɵɵdirectiveInject (core.mjs:14518:1)
at NodeInjectorFactory.FusionChartsComponent_Factory \[as factory\] (fusioncharts.component.js:569:183)
at getNodeInjectable (core.mjs:3574:1)
at instantiateAllDirectives (core.mjs:10417:1)
```

I've checked the compatibility of the libraries
I saw that a similar error was patched in angular-fusionchart v3.2.0 but I couldn't find any other solution